# Simplest way in Ruby to iterate over element plus next element, where "the next element" is nil on the last iteration?

Tags: ruby

I want to loop over an array like `[:foo, :bar, :baz]`.

On each iteration, I want the item *and* the next item. On the last iteration, the "next item" should be `nil`.

So I want to yield in turn `:foo, :bar`, then `:bar, :baz`, and finally `:baz, nil`.

I can think of a few ways of achieving this:

- `my_list.zip(my_list.from(1)) { |item, next_item| … }`
- `my_list.each.with_index(1) { |item, i| next_item = my_list[i] }`
- `[*my_list, nil].each_cons(2) { |item, next_item| … }`

But I feel like I might be missing some simpler way. Am I?

Comment: `each_with_index` is simpler

Comment: `(my_list + [nil]).each_cons(2) { |item, next_item| ....}` or `my_list.each_index { |i| ... }` with block referencing `my_list[i]` and `my_list[i+1]`. Note `my_list[my_list.size] #=> nil`.

Comment: @mechnicov Thanks! Arguably worse if used with other operations like `map` (`map.with_index` vs `map.each_with_index`) but one less method call for `each` cases like in my question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `each_index` was new to me – thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you only every have three non-nil elements in your Array and always want two elements at a time from #each_cons, then just append a nil and call it a day.

```
%i[foo bar baz].push(nil).each_cons(2).map { [_1, _2] }
#=> [[:foo, :bar], [:bar, :baz], [:baz, nil]]
```

Alternatively, you can just reference each indexed element of the named Array by the current or successor index number, because any reference to elements outside the Array's bounds will be nil. For example:

```
array = %i[foo bar baz]
array.each_index.map { [array[_1], array[_1.succ]] }
#=> [[:foo, :bar], [:bar, :baz], [:baz, nil]]
```

In either case, you'll need #map or some other mechanism if you want to return an Array of Array objects. If you want to do something else, like yield, you can do that too.

Note that if you're going to have a variable number of Array elements, or make changes to the number of #each_cons items, then you'll need a different approach. If that is the case, feel free to open a new or related question.

Comment: Thanks! Note that I *always* want a `nil` as the next item on the last iteration, so the even/odd check is not necessary. The question includes an example of `each_cons` with an always-added `nil`. `each_slice` does not do what the question asks for – it shows the next item but then effectively skips over it on the next iteration. Since the trade-offs of this shortcut weren't made explicit, I also want to point out that mutating the array when we don't have to is usually a bad practice. Sometimes it's fine; sometimes it means our change leaks into other code.

Comment: After your edit: `push` still mutates the array, so can still be bug-prone if used with a shared variable. The question *is* about a variable number of array elements (the three-element array is just an example), but the `each_cons` solutions appending a nil work fine with any length array.

Comment: @HenrikN If you don't like #push, feel free to use :+ to return a new Array. And no, #each_cons won't solve all your edge cases by itself. Try #each_cons(8) on a 5-element Array; if you want to always have tail-packed nils sufficient to fill your Array, you're going to need a different approach, likely along the lines of `array.size % each_cons_size` then pack the tail accordingly.

Comment: Yes, just making it explicit for readers that `push` mutates and this can cause sneaky bugs. You are right that if we want more than just the next 1 element, we need to pad with more nils - good clarification  E.g. `(array + Array.new(cons_size.pred)).each_cons(cons_size) { … }`.